# RavenDB queries no longer working in LinqPad

Tags: c#, ravendb, linqpad

It has been a couple of months since I used RavenDB and LinqPad together. Now that I'm trying it again, I'm getting an error when doing something like this:

```
Session.Query<Application>().Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Id}).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Dump();
```

Error:

> The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

After giving up on that, I tried creating my own program in LinqPad. First, I always get this error, no matter what the code looks like:

> Method not found: 'System.DateTime
>   Raven.Abstractions.SystemTime.get_Now()'.

This is the stack trace provided by LinqPad:

> StackTrace       at
>   Raven.Client.Connection.Profiling.ProfilingInformation..ctor(Nullable`1
>   sessionId)    at
>   Raven.Client.Connection.Profiling.ProfilingInformation.CreateProfilingInformation(Nullable`1
>   sessionId) in
>   c:\Work\RavenDB\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\Profiling\ProfilingInformation.cs:line
>   25    at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient..ctor(String url,
>   DocumentConvention convention, ICredentials credentials, Func`2
>   replicationInformerGetter, String databaseName, HttpJsonRequestFactory
>   jsonRequestFactory, Nullable`1 currentSessionId) in
>   c:\Work\RavenDB\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line
>   68    at
>   Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.b__e() in
>   c:\Work\RavenDB\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentStore.cs:line
>   515    at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.Initialize() in
>   c:\Work\RavenDB\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentStore.cs:line
>   383    at
>   RavenLinqpadDriver.RavenContext.InitDocStore(RavenConnectionDialogViewModel
>   conn) in
>   Z:\code\RavenDB-Linqpad-Driver\RavenLinqpadDriver\RavenContext.cs:line
>   107    at
>   RavenLinqpadDriver.RavenContext..ctor(RavenConnectionDialogViewModel
>   connInfo) in
>   Z:\code\RavenDB-Linqpad-Driver\RavenLinqpadDriver\RavenContext.cs:line
>   36    at UserQuery..ctor(RavenConnectionDialogViewModel connInfo) in
>   c:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad\afgmvhfj\query_vmnmpg.cs:line
>   31

And this is the code:

```
void Main()
{
    var theGroup = new AdGroupEnvironments() {Name = "snuh", ModifyableEnvironments = "development,QA"};

    using(var documentStore = new Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore())
    {
        documentStore.Url = "http://localhost:8099";
        documentStore.Initialize();

        using(var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(theGroup);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class AdGroupEnvironments
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ModifyableEnvironments { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

**Edit**

Per [this link](https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RavenDB-Linqpad-Driver/wiki/Getting-Started), Session and DocStore properties no longer exist. So I tried this:

```
Query<Application>().Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Id}).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Dump();
```

And now I'm back to this exception:

> Method not found: 'System.DateTime
>   Raven.Abstractions.SystemTime.get_Now()'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you are using different versions of assemblies.
You probably need to re-compile the LinqPad driver with the latest RavenDB build.

Comment: This is my guess as to what you mean: Get the driver source from here: https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RavenDB-Linqpad-Driver. Then replace the Raven assemblies with the versions that I use. Then compile it and use that with LinqPad.

Comment: Ayende's right. I fell behind on updating the driver with the current version of Raven. It's up to date now as of now (build 2700) and I have every intention :) of keeping it up to date.

Comment: @RonnieOverby I just tried the latest driver and I'm getting this exception: `Method 'Store' in type 'RavenLinqpadDriver.RavenContext' from assembly 'RavenLinqpadDriver, Version=0.5.2750.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aaac23b83559e37f' does not have an implementation.` Any ideas?